# Why Java multidimensional arrays ge ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when the first array is [2] or more?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, multidimensional-array

I am learning Java's Multidimensional arrays. When I set `arr ={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}` and int `x = arr[2 or more][any digit]`, the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` comes out.

```
public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [][] arr= { {4,5,6,7},{1,2,3,8}};
        int x;

        for(int a= 0,b= 0;a<= 3 && b<= 3; a++, b++){
            try {
                x = arr[a][b];
                System.out.println("a = "+ a + " b = "+ b +"\n"+ x +"\nCorrect----------------------");
            }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("a = "+ a + " b = "+ b +"\nERROR------------------");
            }
        }   

    }

}
```

Result:

```
a = 0 b = 0
4
Correct----------------------
a = 1 b = 1
2
Correct----------------------
a = 2 b = 2
ERROR------------------
a = 3 b = 3
ERROR------------------
```

Comment: This is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  2

Comment: because the array only got two elements: first at index 0 = `{4,5,6,7}` and the second at index 1 = `{1,2,3,8}`; nothing left for index 2 or more

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop goes through a 4x4 range, but your array is 2x4.

A 2d array is an array of arrays. The first index is which array you access.

You have two arrays, [4,5,6,7] and [1,2,3,8]

accessing arr[2] means gives me the third array, and you don't have a third array

Answer (score 1):

`int [][] arr= { {4,5,6,7},{1,2,3,8}};` defines an array of 2 `int[]`:

```
arr[0]={4,5,6,7}
arr[1]={1,2,3,8}
```

So `arr[2]` will throw the exception.